# Switching to Windows

Tags: windows

I am new to Ubuntu, and I am having difficulties with it being the only OS on my laptop. I would like to go back to Windows 10 and install Virtual Box, where I will be able to use Ubuntu occasionally. How could I do that?

Comment: That's kind of a long process for a single stack exchange question.  The first part of your question is a duplicate of this https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on  The 2nd part - there are plenty of virtualbox tutorials around, and how to install vb on windows is off topic here.  If you have difficultly installing ubuntu in the vb, come back, but search the site before asking.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Windows 10 key, and a Windows 10 iso.
Then, pretty much the same as a Ubuntu installation, burn the iso to a DVD or USB key, insert it in your computer and install Windows...

Comment: I read somewhere that I will have to delete the partitions Ubuntu uses. Is that true?

Comment: If burning windows ISO from Ubuntu need to use woeusb or mkusb.  Usually just need install windows, can format drive to ntfs first if wanted, but windows should take care of that.